# Is connecting a TcpClient object with host string and port number slower than using an IPEndpoint?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, network-programming

TcpClient has one Connect method which takes a hostname as a string and a port.

```
TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
```

There is another variant which takes an IPEndPoint.

```
TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint endpoint)
```

I assume that the first variant above has to use a DNS lookup to get the IP address from the hostname before establishing the TCP connection while the second does not need to do so. I don't know if the first one is optimized to check whether the hostname just contains the direct IP address or if it does a DNS lookup each  time.

So my question is, Is the second variant faster when I already know the IP address?

P.S.
I am developing for Windows Mobile (6.1) and testing it over a router in my local network. When the router is connected to the open internet, the connections happen fast and I get a quick response from the server. But when I am only using my local network (i.e. router is disconnected from the open internet), connections seem to take forever. Don't know if the open internet somehow speeds up DNS resolution.

Comment: Not an answer but if you've got a complete version of Visual Studio (Ultimate or Pro/Testing editions IIRC), you can simulate network setups and monitor traffic through the testing tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens just the way you assumed, the first overload (hostname, port) internally performs a DNS lookup and then calls the second overload (IPEndPoint). If you want to see what exactly happens, you could download .NET Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) and inspect the `TcpClient` class.

By reading the background information it looks like the device still tries to use the DNS it can no longer connect to, hitting the timeout. I don't know enough about networking to back that assumption up, though.